Hibernate 6 Postgres bytea, Oracle varchar2 mapping in a JPA Entity
I have a column in my jpa entity where it should be mapped to bytea in Postgres and varchar2(1024) in oracle.
@Column(name="users")
private String users;

I'm using hibernate 6.2.28.Final jars along with spring-orm 6.x and JDK 21. Please help me with this.
I have tried a custom @Convert like below, this works for postgres. But it is storing the byte array data in oracle as well. It should store bytea data in postgres and normal data in oracle.

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import jakarta.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = false)
public class StringByteArrayConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, byte[]> {

    @Override
    public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return attribute.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new String (dbData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}


Solved the problem by implementing a custom @JavaType.
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.WrapperOptions;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcTypeIndicators;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.spi.JdbcTypeRegistry;
import org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration;


public class CustomStringJavaType extends StringJavaType {

    
    @Override
    public JdbcType getRecommendedJdbcType(JdbcTypeIndicators stdIndicators) {
        if (stdIndicators.getDialect() instanceof PostgreSQLDialect){
            TypeConfiguration typeConfiguration = stdIndicators.getTypeConfiguration();
            JdbcTypeRegistry registry = typeConfiguration.getJdbcTypeRegistry();
            return registry.getDescriptor(Types.BINARY); // Maps to bytea in PostgreSQL
        }
        return super.getRecommendedJdbcType( stdIndicators );
    }

    
    public <X> X unwrap(String value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (byte[].class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return value != null ? (X) value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : null;
        }
        return super.unwrap(value, type, options);
    }

    
    public <X> String wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value instanceof byte[]){
            return value != null ? new String((byte[]) value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) : null;
        }
        return super.wrap(value, options);
    }

}

used this CustomStringJavaType like below in the entity.
@Column(name = "users")
@JavaType(value= CustomStringJavaType.class)
private String users;

Here is column type and database which it is getting mapped to.



Postgres
MySQL
Oracle
MsSQL




bytea
blob, varchar
clob
text, nvarchar



